# Image Mean Subtraction in Custom Caffe Dataset?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am currently in the process of creating a dataset of images to train, validate, and test a basic custom ConvNet using Caffe.

Specifically, I have collected my JPG images (RGB), and am now deciding how to preprocess the images for my network. I am looking to apply basic normalization to the images, such as subtracting the image mean to 'center' the images.

The ImageNet tutorial http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html mentions this operation, describing how to generate a mean `.binaryproto` file for the dataset by passing the LMDB to the `compute_image_mean` executable in `$CAFFE_HOME/build/tools`.

I have done this, and now have a `.binaryproto` file for my training LMDB. To my understanding, this file essentially contains a representation of the mean pixel values of all images in the passed LMDB. Therefore, I suppose that it is storing some form of array containing pixel values for the three channels.

---

**Questions:**

How do I use this `.binaryproto` file to perform the mean subtraction?

Should I be creating separate `.binaryproto` files for each of my LMDBs (train, validate, test)? Or should I create one LMDB containing all images in the dataset first, generate the mean from that, and apply the subtraction to all subsets?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain the `.binaryproto` file using only your training set, and use it while training, validating, as well as testing.

This is because if you take the mean of all the images, you are indirectly providing information to the network about the nature of the validation and test images while training, which might help it perform better than it would otherwise have.

As you might know, you need to add it in your data layer in your `prototxt` file under `transform_param`.

```
layer {
    name: "data" #the name
    # other attributes
    transform_param {
        mean_file: "path/to/training/binaryproto"
    }
}
```

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185582/150154) on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) also refers to the same query, which also links to [this useful resource](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#datapre).